# JavaFX someNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() выдает 0.0

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте, я занимаюсь изучением javafx, и мне надо написать чтобы при добавлении "нода" на "сцену" окно само увеличивалось на нужный размер.
(`window.setHeight(window.getHeight() + myNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());`), но `myNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()` выдает 0.0.

Весь код:

```
MyNode myNode = new RootFinderResult(findersNames);
vBox.getChildren().add(myNode);
window.setHeight(window.getHeight() + myNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `AWT`, вы можете добавить интерфейс `ComponentListener` в `JPanel`, а затем переопределить метод `componentResized()`, чтобы получить новые значения ширины и высоты. Попробуйте прописать слушатель `ComponentAdapter` к примеру таким образом:

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
System.out.println("Новая ширина: " + getWidth() + " Новая высота: " + getHeight());
}
});
```

В `JavaFX` скорее всего не получится это сделать, возможно вам подойдет второй вариант:

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
@Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> 
observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {
    System.out.println("Ширина: " + newSceneWidth);
}
});
scene.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
@Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> 
observableValue, Number oldSceneHeight, Number newSceneHeight) {
    System.out.println("Высота: " + newSceneHeight);
}
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Но лучше с лямбдой (myNode.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { };)

Comment: @ScreamTV5 не за что, надеюсь, что помог ответом. Лямбда или нет, это дело вкуса.